# Android How to Exit our application when Exit button click

Tags: android

When User click "Exit" button, Its go to device home screen.Then again click/select my application its go to last opened activity.I houldn't go there.It need to  go initial screen.How we can implement this.I have done using :

```
public void onExitAction(View botton){
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myLogedPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    myPrefs.edit().remove("myLogedPrefs");
    myPrefs.edit().clear(); 
    myPrefs.edit().commit();
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    finish();      
}
```

Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 1):

Android applications don't have "exit" buttons.  If you look at all of the applications that are part of the platform, none of them have exit buttons or menus.

If you want the user to return to the root activity of your app each time they launch it from its icon in the launcher, use this in your manifest:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear

Comment: iN MY APPLICATION i HAVE "EXIT" button . When User click that one it need to go homescreen. That is ok. Calling back my app(Main Grid --> select my app) then its go to Last opens.That is the issue

Comment: A lot of apps have Exit menu buttons. Especially useful for apps which run in the background by design, providing the user an easy way to end them.

Comment: Actually, Google Analytics uses an Exit button in their sample App.

Comment: @CrackerJack9 no this is mixing two very different things.  If an app has something of interest it can do in the background, it makes fine sense to have a UI to control it.  Starting/stopping music playback, navigation, being signed in to chat, etc.  Again look at the standard platform.  You will not see an exit button anywhere.  You will certainly see things to control what an application does in the background, but this is not at all the same thing.  And if Google Analytics has an actual exit button, then it is stupid, and don't copy it and be stupid as well. :p

Comment: @hackbod seem to be hung up on a label. what's the difference betweeen a button that says 'Stop background service' and one that says 'Exit' if they both do the same thing?

Comment: They definitely do not.  Pretty universally when people ask about how to make an exit command, they are thinking about things as a desktop app, where they "exit" and all of the windows go away, the process goes away, etc.  This is not a model that is appropriate for Android.  A button that lets you stop a background service only impacts that background service -- if it is implemented as a Service, then that Service is destroyed, but your application's activities remain as well as its process.  Or this may just remove an alarm manager alarm.  Either way, very different from quit the app.

Answer (score -2):

```
public void quit() {
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

and on exit button just call this method

```
btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        try {
                        quit(); 
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: No, don't kill your process.  Don't quit your process.

Comment: ya actually you are forcing the process to kill its not a healthy approach